# JAVA JPA List affected by other list

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

Im using Hibernate and a MySQL database.

and i have a strange problem.

```
@XmlElement
@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<String> features;

@XmlElement
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ExtraList> extraLists;
```

i am using a facade to retrieve the data. When i get the object from the database. feature list has 5 items (as i should). But the extraLists also has 5 items. this list should only contain a single object. but it contains as much duplicates of that object as there are items in the feature list.

if i change the feature list to 4 items the extraLists will also contain 4 items.

I tried to google but i don't know how to google for this problem and couldn't find any good results.

Comment: Use Set instead of List for at least one of these collections.

Comment: As I recall, this is an issue with `FetchType.EAGER` in combination with a `List` rather than a `Set`; use either `FetchType.LAZY` or a `Set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JB Nizet and @beerbajay where correct. using a Set fixes my problems. Unfortuanly i cant upvote their commen

Answer (score 0):

You should use a query like this one:

```
select distinct e
from MyEntity e
left join fetch e.extraLists
where e.id = :id
```

1. The one-to-many collection should use `FetchType.LAZY` so you use the [query-time fetch directive](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) to load the collection along with the root entity
2. The `distinct` keyword tell Hibernate to drop object reference duplicates

Comment: The database contains a single item. The problem is with jpa when retrieving them